# Programmatically retrieve indexs in sqlite

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

Is there any way to view existing index declarations in `sqlite3`? I need to find out on runtime whether or not there are index's on certain columns, and so far I cannot find anywhere that explains how to retrieve the declarations without using the `sqlite3 CLI`.

Comment: In general your app should not concern itself with DDL concerns at runtime. What's the bigger problem you're trying to address?

Comment: On runtime, I am either creating a new table -- in which I can skip this check, there will be no index's set; or using an existing table. However, this table may or may not have the same index's set, so I need to find out what index's are set, and what index's aren't so I can "fill in the gaps" where needed.

Comment: Again, why is your application code mucking around with DDL? Creating new tables _should_ really be outside of the scope of your application's concern, unless you happen to be writing, say, an Android app. What's stopping you from manually setting up your schema once and entirely outside of the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of a table's indexes by executing [PRAGMA index_list](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_index_list), and the list of columns in an index with [PRAGMA index_info](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_index_info).